# using match query on a field

Tags: elasticsearch

query the index  for a type   with query string to match any property

```
{
    "size": 2,
     "_source":["awardeeName"],
    "query": {
        "query_string" : {
                "query": "health"
             }
    }
  }         
}
```

this returns two records

```
[
{
    "_index": "docm-es",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "9d8c832d-f22f-463e-9102-4aefcaff88fa",
    "_score": 0.74211,
    "_source": {
        "awardeeName": "State of Hawaii Department of Health"
    }
},
{
    "_index": "docm-es",
    "_type": "document",
    "_id": "79963a60-8e9e-45ac-b7f8-6dc99f6b0621",
    "_score": 0.6427368,
    "_source": {
        "awardeeName": "New York State Department of Health"
    }
}
]
```

Both the records show, property awardeename contains word health.
Query to search with match on field awardeeName for text health,

```
{
    "size": 2,
    "_source":["awardeeName"],
    "query": {
        "match" : {
                "awardeeName": "health"
             }
    }
  }         
}
```

this does not return any hits, what is wrong , in  this query, Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Can you update the question by adding the mapping you are using for this field

Comment: I saw the mapping , awardeeName field is not analyzed, I learnt it should be indexed for full text search